# why is my html table not autofitting?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have downloaded stack exchange data dumps from internet archive which is in xml format. I used xslt to transform it to html. Now everything is working fine except that the table doesn't autofit. I have widht assigned as 100% and experimented with the div too. Any help?

```
<table border="1" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Body</th>

    </tr>
    <!-- for-each processing instruction
          Looks for each element matching the XPAth expression
           -->
    <xsl:for-each select="posts/row">

    <tr>
      <td width="30%">
        <!-- value-of processing instruction
        process the value of the element matching the XPath expression
        -->
        <xsl:value-of select="@Title"/>
      </td>
      <td width="70%"><xsl:value-of select="@Body" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></td>

    </tr>

    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
```

I tried styling with external CSS too but it doesn't work either. Does it have anything to do with how the xml data is structured? If so then please have a look at this data too which is in internet archive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need set a width on the parent container.

```
<body>
    <div style="width:400px">
        <table>
            content
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

width can be set to 100% as well.
fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/epg2775r/

please note that using attributes like bgcolor, width and cellspacing are obsolete and CSS should be used instead.

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: what you see above is the basic logic of the html. I am using xslt to display xml in htmlesque format

Comment: Hm... your Browswer maybe? i dont quite understand the problem i guess :(

Comment: my guess is something inside of xml data is overriding the html rules and extending the table, would you have a look at stack exchange's data dump and it's structure at internet archive?